# Make control flow analysis work in inductive case

Tags: typescript

Sanity checks like the following appear in a long sequence in my code:

```
if (!someCheck() /* dependent on previously assigned variables */) {
    console.log(someMessage);
    return;
}
someVariables = something; // dependent on someCheck being successful
```

Here, `someCheck` typically uses variables set earlier. It somewhat reminds me a bit of "checking deeply nested properties", which nowadays `?.` solves.

I wanted to shorten this pattern, so it is less repetitive (don't have to write the `if`, `return`, `console.log`, ..., every time). I've thought of the following scheme:

```
let varOne = null,
    varTwo = null,
    varThree = null;

let checkAssign = [
    [() => true,                     () => { varOne = { prop: "hello" }; varTwo = ["myData"]; }, "msg1"],
    [() => varOne.prop.length === 5, () => { varThree = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]; },      "msg2"],
    [() => varTwo[0] === "myData",   () => { /* no assignments here, can be empty */ },          "msg3"],
]

for (let [check, assign, message] of checkAssign) {
    if (check()) assign();
    else {
        console.log(message);
        return;
    }
}
```

However, I assume it is too difficult for flow analysis to understand the inductive principle, where pseudo-mathematically speaking, `{ assign#1, ..., assign#N-1 } --> variables_for_check#N`, and that they are only executed in order. Therefore, although it should be clear at compile-time, whether variables will be assigned prior to a check, I'd have to add a runtime check, to assert to the type-checker, that everything is ok (admittedly there may be some not-so-verbose solutions here, maybe i could just not care, if there is a really short one).

Is there a way to have the type-checker understand the situation here, or a different way to express the situation, where the type-checker understands it, yet still not as verbose as chaining a bazillion multi-line if-statements?

---

Additional notes that are imho not essential:

- A functional-oriented approach, where `assign#N-1` returns all data for `check#N` would be another idea. However, to me, it seems equally difficult, to make the type-checker assert, that the list is `#N-1 --> #N` (very similar issue imho).
- I don't think this is relevant, but to elaborate the situation: The program is analyzing and modifying code (think babel, eslint, ...). The checks are typically verifying, whether the part of the AST, that is currently being looked at, is of a certain structure, while extracting data. Examples for checks/assignment pairs would be:

  - "does X exist?" before "readableNameForX = X"
  - "is property Y being named by an identifier, and not a literal?" (`({ prop: value })` vs `({ "prop": value })`), before `readableNameForY = identifier`

  (almost always just for readability - the full path is often very long, and a name helps identify what it really is quickly).